# Docker Build with /dev/shm exec

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm trying to build a docker image and the building process requires the /dev/shm to have exec but by default /dev/shm is mounted with noexec. I know I can do a `docker run --tmpfs /dev/shm:rw,exec imagename` and then everything works but there seems to be no equivalent in docker build.

Comment: Have you tried `--shm-size` option of `docker build`. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/builder_build/ Check if this option helps with noexec.

Comment: Why do you need shared memory during the image build?  Can you include a sample Dockerfile that illustrates your use case?

Comment: @mchawre Yes but that doesn't help, I need exec which has nothing to do with size

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm creating an Oracle container with a populated database. The data comes from an Oracle dump using the command impdp which requires /dev/shm to be exec. https://dbacentrals.blogspot.com/2017/07/ora-00600-internal-error-code-arguments.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bit late, but for anyone else who ends up here, there's a flag you can use in dockerfiles for BuildKit that lets you do file system mounts at build time. By changing your dockerfile's RUN line to include a mount flag, you can overwrite the builders usual shared memory directory with a new temporary file system that has the right permissions. I've found that the following works:

```
RUN --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/dev/shm,rw \
    yourDatabaseImportScript.sh
```

This will require the machine you're using to build the image [has BuildKit enabled](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds)

[BuildKit mounts flag documentation](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#build-mounts-run---mount)
[Setting permissions on BuildKit tmpfs mounts](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/910)
[Oracle's FAQ answer on permissions needed for `/dev/shm`](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/FAQ.md#ora-00600-internal-error-code-arguments-pesldl03_mmap-errno-1-errmsg-operation-not-permitted-----------)